# Run rake task from rails migration file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, rake

I have a rake task that I run from the terminal using the command below.

```
bundle exec rake migrations:seed_us_users
```

I have created this migration file but I don’t know how the code should be to run this rake task.

```
class AddNewUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute a rake task from within a loaded Rails environment with either

```
Rake::Task['migrations:seed_us_users'].invoke or Rake::Task['migrations:seed_us_users'].execute
```

You can pass data to the task inside of the invoke or execute method. Example:

```
Rake::Task['migrations:seed_us_users'].invoke(params)
```

For more details please check
https://sampatbadhe.medium.com/rake-task-invoke-or-execute-419cd689c3bd